# Window stock executables are missing [Compatibility] Tab, why?

Tags: windows-10

I got a problem on Windows 10 (21H1). I want to change DPI scaling behavior for mstsc, but find that there is no [Compatibility] Tab for mstsc, which defeats my intention.

After some poking around, I find that Windows stock executables, like mstsc.exe, notepad.exe, regedit.exe, do **NOT** exhibit this [Compatibility] Tab, while all third party exe do.

I really need this for mstsc.exe, bcz mstsc's default behavior is silly. If I drag its window(displaying a remote PC screen) from a 120dpi monitor to a 96dpi monitor, I see mstsc's window frame shrink(☹), but its window content scaling keeps intact(), so the scroll bar appears(☹). My monitors are big enough and I don't want that boring scrollbar, in other word, pixel-to-pixel accurate display of remote PC screen is my desired behavior.

Is there way to fix this problem?

[image]

### ==== UPDATE ====

In comment, Danial suggests editing the registry. Looks a feasible approach, but tried and disappointed, still no effect.

[image]

Comment: IIRC you can edit the registry directly and it'll still apply. I'll take a look later. You could also use a different RDP client.

Comment: @Jimm - I went back years into Windows 7 and the overall compatibility options for stock Windows apps has not changed. I amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> I find that Windows stock executables, like mstsc.exe, notepad.exe,
> regedit.exe, do NOT exhibit this [Compatibility] Tab, while all third
> party exe do.

Entirely normal situation for Windows 10 (and even as far back as Windows 7).

Microsoft writes Windows and writes the "stock" executable software. They provide the correct version for the Windows you are running, so the software does not need a compatibility setting.

Third party software may be misaligned with specific versions of Windows and so they provide a compatibility tab in the odd event you need to run the software in compatibility mode to make it run.

Good software keeps up to date so everything I have runs without running in compatibility mode.

That is all the tab is for:  older, legacy software needing to run in compatibility mode.

Windows "stock" software does not need this mode because it comes for the version of Windows being used.

Current Microsoft Office apps also do not have the compatibility tab.

**Follow up:**

For Windows 7, "stock" apps have the Compatibility Tab, but the compatibility options are greyed out.

For non-"stock" apps, the compatibility options are not greyed out.

So the overall compatibility options we see have been around for a long time.

You may have to try a different remote client to fit your needs.